# Running custom MSBuild tasks as part of the git deployment to Azure WebSites

Tags: msbuild, azure, azure-web-app-service

### Problem

As part of my csproj I have a custom MSBuild task that executes the YUICompressor and generates a compiled css and js file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CssOutputFile>$(OutDir)..\Styles\compiled.css</CssOutputFile>
    <JavaScriptOutputFile>$(OutDir)..\Scripts\compiled.js</JavaScriptOutputFile>
    <BuildDependsOn Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
      $(BuildDependsOn);
      CompressorTarget;
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This runs fine as part of the git deployment and the file is being generated, however the Azure Web Sites deployment engine will then copy all the output files to another folder. In that process it seems it takes whatever you have in your `csproj` instead of whatever you have in the folder. That menas that the generated compiled.css and compiled.js won't be copied (because they are not in my csproj)

Answer (score 2):

What Azure does to deploy your project should be exactly the same as if you do the following:

- Right click on the project and choose Publish
- Change the Publish Method to 'File System'
- Enter a path and click Publish

So generally, you'll want to make sure that your build process works such that you get the right file when you do this local publish. If it does, then chances are you'll get the same results when git pushing to Azure.

Comment: should it run Web.config transforms as part of that publish process?  It seems not to do so at the moment (or I've made a mistake in my transform).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I used for now is adding an empty compiled.css and .js file to the csproj and I wanted to write this question in case someone goes through the same thing.

It would be great if someone from MS can comment if there are plans on doing something different for this scenario.

Comment: Is there something in the 1.7 SDK that makes adding files to the .cspkg file easier?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you place the compiled scripts, you can use star-includes in your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="assets\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If Azure uses your project file to determine what gets deployed (which seems somewhat strange to start with), then that should work.

Comment: Thanks! I can try that although I would need to add a special folder.  I am doing an experiment here and want to have my app working on apphb and Azure Web Sites. Is this going to work with apphb?